# Selenium 2/Webdriver - how to double click a table row (which opens a new window)

Tags: c#, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using C# with Selenium 2.0 / Webdriver and I'm trying to simulate a double click on a table row that opens a new browser window.

I have two problems:

1. After locating the table row which has a unique classname (i.e. using `findelement(By.classname("...")))` applying the click method (or select/submit) does not perform any action and complains about not being able to perform that kind action on the element in question.
2. How do you perform a double click in Selenium 2.0/Webdriver ?

Answer (score 8):

1. You should click on the table cell (`<td>`) element
2. Double click is not yet implemented in WebDriver. See [Issue #244](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=244) for the status. Also the comments to this issue contains a JavaScript that can be used to to the double click in Firefox.

For IE you will need to execute the following:

```
(IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].fireEvent('ondblclick');", cell);
```

For the Firefox and Chrome:

```
(IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" +
        "evt.initMouseEvent('dblclick',true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0,null);" +
        "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evt);", cell);
```

where the `cell` is the web element on which you would like to execute the script.

Comment: +1 - Still a great alternative for when the out-of-the-box DoubleClick doesn't do what you want it to do. Worked perfect for me

Comment: Still true in 2017 - aiming the double click at the td was the key to getting it working for me.

Answer (score 5):

For double click you can perform following:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

action_chains = ActionChains(driver)
action_chians.double_click(on_element).perform()
```

*where, on_element = element on which you want to double click*

I did this using python. and it worked :)