# Selenium webdriver actions on element will be executed in wrong location

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, location, webdriver

I'm trying to build my first test with selenium and got a problem.

I'm searching for a element, no problem. I can click on it, get the
text in the element... every thing works fine.
But double click on the element just doesn't work. Selenium
clicks in the wrong location. I made a screenshot of this situation:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49ovb.jpg)

To find the row i use xpath and search for the text in the cell, but this text is unique(I checked it)

```
private readonly string _identityPath = ".//td[.= 'All Employees']";

...

mainPage.FindElement(By.XPath(_identityPath)).Click(); //Works(dotted box)

Actions builder = new Actions(mainPage);

IAction doubleClick = builder.DoubleClick(mainPage.FindElement(By.XPath(_identityPath))).Build();
doubleClick.Perform(); //wrong location/element

/*
Actions action = new Actions(mainPage);
action.DoubleClick(mainPage.FindElement(By.XPath(_identityPath))); 
action.Perform(); *///wrong location/element
```

This page is in an iframe and the grid is a dojo component... maybe the problem
comes from there. Any ideas whats wrong? I have no idea where this is coming from. :/

Greets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common issue that Actions builder does not work.
Using JavaScript should help - find answer in this thread:

[Selenium 2/Webdriver - how to double click a table row (which opens a new window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982442/selenium-2-webdriver-how-to-double-click-a-table-row-which-opens-a-new-window)

Answer (score 0):

If the element is in an iframe, you need to switch to that iframe in order to interact with the element.